# Is there any way that particular apk is terminate automatically after some time from android device

Tags: android

I have a apk file of android project and install application in android device from that apk and i want that it will be terminate after some time which i have given to it from android device.how can it be possible..

Thanx in advance...

Comment: what do you mean by destroy after some time??

Comment: the application which install in android device it will hide/terminate after some time.

Comment: you mean to have a *virous* app.!!

Comment: no, i mean to say can i acheived this by writing some code in my android project.

Comment: Do you want to kill the whole application process or just the current activity?

Comment: I guess you want to implement Licensing model for your application. So that user able to use your application for a specific time period. is this??

Comment: i want to kill whole application automatically from device in a given time.

Comment: i want to achieve this through coding.